# Determining the $C_w$ Value of a Random Variable based on Distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

In my probability class, random variables X were defined as $$X=\sum_{S=w}1_{\{w\}}C_w$$ where $C_w$ is some number for an outcome w. It seems to me that there's a relationship between the type of distribution for a random variable and its $C_w$ value. Is there? And if so, how does one determine a distribution given a $C_w$, and how does one determine a $C_w$ for a distribution? I don't really understand this formula, so I'm looking to get a better grip on it.

I haven't learned beyond simple counting, conditional probability, random variables and distributions in this course yet, so that if you could make your answer accessible to that level of knowledge that would be appreciated.

If I'm mislead in asking this, please let me know and I will take down this post.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S$ is the sample space and $\omega \in S$ is one of the outcome. So I guess the definition is written as
$$ X = \sum_{\omega \in S} 1_{\{\omega\}} C_\omega$$

I think to understand it probably we just need to illustrate with a simple example. Consider the experiment of flipping a fair coin.
Let the sample space
$$ S = \{\omega_H, \omega_T \} $$
where $\omega_H$ denote the outcome being head and $\omega$ denote the outcome being tail.

Note that a random variable $X$ is a function that map from the sample space to a measurable space. Here we can take the sample space $S$ and map to $\{0, 1\}$ with
$$ X(\omega_H) = 0, X(\omega_T) = 1$$
It means that
$$ X = \begin{cases} X(\omega_H) = 0 & \text{if} & \text{Outcome is Head} \\
X(\omega_T) = 1 & \text{if} & \text{Outcome is Tail} \end{cases}$$

Here we usually call the set $\{0, 1\}$ that the random variable $X$ map to the support of $X$.

Here in your notation, $1$ is the indicator function which gives

$$ 1_{\{\omega\}} = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if Outcome is } \omega \\
0 & \text{Otherwise} \end{cases}$$

And we can define $C_\omega = X(\omega) $ be the support point. In many usages we usually suppress the notation $X(\omega)$ and simply write $X$, but actually we need to bear this concept in mind. So we can rewrite as

$$ X = \begin{cases} C_{\omega_H} = 0 & \text{if} & \text{Outcome is Head} \\
C_{\omega_T} = 1 & \text{if} & \text{Outcome is Tail} \end{cases}$$

So by the definition of indicator function, we can write this as

$$ X = 1_{\{\omega_H\}}C_{\omega_H} + 1_{\{\omega_T\}}C_{\omega_T}$$

which is the summation in the definition. This concept can be generalized to the other random variables as well.

Also you may also want to understand the following probability notation / concepts:
$$ \Pr\{X = 0\} = \Pr\{\omega: X(\omega) = 0\} = \Pr\{\omega_H\}$$
which is the probability of the outcome is Head.

Comment: Oh I see! I didn't realize that the $C_w$ value was assigned on a per-event basis. So the distribution isn't directly related to the assignment of $C_w$ values? Is there any way in which $C_w$ can indicate what type of distribution is used for a random variable?

Comment: Here the set of $C_\omega$ only gives you the support, but not the probability yet. So for the same set of $C_\omega$, you can still have different distributions. In the example here, $X$ is a Bernoulli random variable with support $\{0, 1\}$. Then we can consider a fair coin $p = 1/2$ and an unfair coin $p \neq 1/2$. So this gives a different probability measure (distribution), although the sample space, event space and the random variable are identical.